# Get List Of Connected Joysticks using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, joystick

I'm looking for a way that I can get list of connected joysticks via VBScript just like in the picture below (I mean the order of them is highly important):

[image: joy.cpl is list the connected joysticks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to do that... hard to find on net...

```
strComputer = "." Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ &
"{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "oot\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from
Win32_PnPEntity")

For Each objItem in colItems

Wscript.Echo "Class GUID: " & objItem.ClassGuid
Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
Wscript.Echo "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID
Wscript.Echo "Manufacturer: " & objItem.Manufacturer
Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
Wscript.Echo "PNP Device ID: " & objItem.PNPDeviceID
Wscript.Echo "Service: " & objItem.Service

Next
```

Hope [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/hardware/devices/hwdevbo3.mspx) helps

Comment: Thanks for your script, But it will show so many many unwanted devices too. for example if one joystick is connected, this script will show about 25 other devices too and it is not what I'm looking for, I only need the name of joystick or their VID and PID Ids and the order of them just like in the picture is important for me, BTW thanks again for your time :))

Comment: what is the purpose of having them in VBScript only?

Comment: I have an application that can only read from vbscripts, I mean it can read the output of a vbscript.